# Where to read about integrals of vector-valued functions against vector-valued measures?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I would like to understand the theory of integration of functions taking values in Banach spaces against Banach-valued measures. To this end, I found that at the end of Chapter 2 of [Vector Measures](https://books.google.com/books/about/Vector_Measures.html?id=fEKZAwAAQBAJ), the author refers the reader to a 1956 construction termed the Bartle integral. Is [this 1956 paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm15/sm15131.pdf) the best or most up-to-date reference to understand this topic? For example, a specific question that comes up in my research is whether Fubini is valid for integrals against Banach-valued measures.

Comment: Is there any suggestion that can be made? Is the generalisation from the Bochner integral trivial?